# How to start SPSS-statistics 23 in Debian?

Tags: debian, software-installation, java, d-bus, spss-statistics

I installed the university licence in Debian 8.5 but did not configure any paths and forgot what is the default location. 
I cannot see in anything in $PATH about the program by searching *SPSS*. Installation iterations

1. I installed the system as non-root first time, but found later that it should be done as root.
2. Now, second time, I installed it as root, because the installation documentation says so, for the user *masi*

   ```
   # let the IBM directory be executable by the user masi
   chown -R masi:masi /opt/IBM/
   root@root:~/Downloads$ bash ./SPSSSC_23.0_LINUX_X86-64_ML.bin
   ```

   - Output in trying to register the product in IBM website. Fig. 1 *No D-bus daemon running* message after installation of SPSS as root

     [image]
3. Now, third time, let the binary be executable explicitly by masi, but as you can see later everything is in order in (2), since same output here too

   ```
   root@masi:/home/masi/Downloads# chmod u+x SPSSSC_23.0_LINUX_X86-64_ML.bin 
   root@masi:/home/masi/Downloads$ ./SPSSSC_23.0_LINUX_X86-64_ML.bin
   ```

   - Set user `masi`. Click accept to everything. Entered successfully the serial code. Try to register the product but get exactly the same output is in Fig. 1.
   - Try table completion for `sp` but you get

     ```
     masi@masi:~/Downloads$ sp
     spctoppm           speaker-test       speech-dispatcher  splitfont          spotread           sputoppm
     spd-conf           spec2cie           splain             splitindex         sprof              spuunmux
     spd-say            specplot           split              splitti3           spumux
     ```
   - Try to find *spss* in Debian search under <kbd>super</kbd> but nothing there.

Characteristics of my system before the installation I did earlier as root `chown -R masi:masi /opt/IBM/`

```
masi@masi:~/Downloads$ ls -la /opt/
total 20
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4096 Sep 15 00:01 .
drwxr-xr-x 22 root root 4096 Sep 15 13:21 ..
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Sep  1 22:58 google
drwxrwxr-x  3 masi masi 4096 Sep 15 00:01 IBM
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Sep 11 10:23 kingsoft

masi@masi:~/Downloads$ ls -la /opt/IBM/
total 12
drwxrwxr-x 3 masi masi 4096 Sep 15 00:01 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Sep 15 00:01 ..
drwxrwxr-x 3 masi masi 4096 Sep 15 00:01 SPSS

masi@masi:~/Downloads$ ls -la /opt/IBM/SPSS/
total 12
drwxrwxr-x 3 masi masi 4096 Sep 15 00:01 .
drwxrwxr-x 3 masi masi 4096 Sep 15 00:01 ..
drwxrwxr-x 3 masi masi 4096 Sep 15 00:01 Statistics

masi@masi:~/Downloads$ ls -la /opt/IBM/SPSS/Statistics/
total 12
drwxrwxr-x  3 masi masi 4096 Sep 15 00:01 .
drwxrwxr-x  3 masi masi 4096 Sep 15 00:01 ..
drwxrwxr-x 15 masi masi 4096 Sep 15 13:17 23

masi@masi:~/Downloads$ ls -la /opt/IBM/SPSS/Statistics/23/
total 92
drwxrwxr-x 15 masi masi  4096 Sep 15 13:17 .
drwxrwxr-x  3 masi masi  4096 Sep 15 00:01 ..
drwxr-xr-x 10 masi masi 12288 Sep 15 13:22 bin
drwxr-xr-x  4 masi masi  4096 Feb 12  2015 common
drwxr-xr-x  2 masi masi  4096 Feb 12  2015 config
drwxr-xr-x  4 masi masi  4096 Feb 12  2015 ext
drwxr-xr-x 40 masi masi  4096 Sep 15 13:17 extensions
drwxr-xr-x  4 masi masi 20480 Sep 15 13:17 lib
drwxrwxr-x  3 masi masi  4096 Sep 15 00:04 license
drwxrwxr-x  2 masi masi  4096 Sep 15 00:04 Looks
drwxrwxr-x  3 masi masi  4096 Sep 15 00:04 properties
drwxrwxr-x  7 masi masi  4096 Sep 15 00:04 Python
drwxrwxr-x  3 masi masi  4096 Sep 15 00:04 Samples
drwxr-xr-x  2 masi masi  4096 Feb  4  2015 scripts
-rw-rw-r--  1 root root     0 Sep 15 13:17 SPSS_Statistics_23.0.spec
-rwxr-xr-x  1 masi masi   580 Sep 13  2013 tar.sh
drwxrwxr-x  3 masi masi  4096 Sep 15 00:06 Uninstall_IBM SPSS Statistics 23
```

I think the problem is that SPSS is not in my PATH and do not know which command to start.

### Official installation instructions

> ```
> Installing from a Downloaded File E Start a terminal application. 
> E Change to the directory where you downloaded the file. 
> E Extract the contents of the file. 
> E Change to the directory where you extracted the files. 
> E Make sure the permissions for setup.bin are set to execute. 
> E At the command prompt, type: ./setup.bin 
> E Follow the instructions that appear in the installation program. See Notes for Installation for any special instructions.
> ```

### Testing Launo's proposal

Work flow after the installation as root

```
root@masi:/home/masi# apt-get install dbus
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
dbus is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up nginx-full (1.6.2-5+deb8u2+b1) ...
Job for nginx.service failed. See 'systemctl status nginx.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript nginx, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package nginx-full (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nginx:
 nginx depends on nginx-full (>= 1.6.2-5+deb8u2) | nginx-light (>= 1.6.2-5+deb8u2) | nginx-extras (>= 1.6.2-5+deb8u2); however:
  Package nginx-full is not configured yet.
  Package nginx-light is not installed.
  Package nginx-extras is not installed.
 nginx depends on nginx-full (<< 1.6.2-5+deb8u2.1~) | nginx-light (<< 1.6.2-5+deb8u2.1~) | nginx-extras (<< 1.6.2-5+deb8u2.1~); however:
  Package nginx-full is not configured yet.
  Package nginx-light is not installed.
  Package nginx-extras is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package nginx (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nginx-full
 nginx
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Trying to install Java JRE after the installation as root

```
# https://wiki.debian.org/Java
root@masi:/home/masi# apt-get install default-jre
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  default-jre
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 968 B of archives.
After this operation, 21.5 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://ftp.fi.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main default-jre amd64 2:1.7-52 [968 B]
Fetched 968 B in 0s (21.7 kB/s)      
Selecting previously unselected package default-jre.
(Reading database ... 265271 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../default-jre_2%3a1.7-52_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking default-jre (2:1.7-52) ...
Setting up nginx-full (1.6.2-5+deb8u2+b1) ...
Job for nginx.service failed. See 'systemctl status nginx.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript nginx, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package nginx-full (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nginx:
 nginx depends on nginx-full (>= 1.6.2-5+deb8u2) | nginx-light (>= 1.6.2-5+deb8u2) | nginx-extras (>= 1.6.2-5+deb8u2); however:
  Package nginx-full is not configured yet.
  Package nginx-light is not installed.
  Package nginx-extras is not installed.
 nginx depends on nginx-full (<< 1.6.2-5+deb8u2.1~) | nginx-light (<< 1.6.2-5+deb8u2.1~) | nginx-extras (<< 1.6.2-5+deb8u2.1~); however:
  Package nginx-full is not configured yet.
  Package nginx-light is not installed.
  Package nginx-extras is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package nginx (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up default-jre (2:1.7-52) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nginx-full
 nginx
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Studying the failures as encouraged in the log messages above

```
root@masi:/home/masi# systemctl status nginx.service
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2016-09-16 19:41:12 EEST; 1h 26min ago
  Process: 10908 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 10905 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Sep 16 19:41:11 masi nginx[10908]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Sep 16 19:41:11 masi nginx[10908]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Sep 16 19:41:11 masi nginx[10908]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Sep 16 19:41:11 masi nginx[10908]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Sep 16 19:41:12 masi nginx[10908]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Sep 16 19:41:12 masi nginx[10908]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Sep 16 19:41:12 masi nginx[10908]: nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
Sep 16 19:41:12 masi systemd[1]: nginx.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Sep 16 19:41:12 masi systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
Sep 16 19:41:12 masi systemd[1]: Unit nginx.service entered failed state.
```

Studying the failures by `journalctl -xn` where the addon `adblock` seems to be blocking some network traffic so may explain the `d-bus` warning, so possible not related why I cannot launch SPSS in Terminal

```
lines 1-11/11 (END)...skipping...
-- Logs begin at Fri 2016-09-09 12:00:17 EEST, end at Fri 2016-09-16 21:02:26 EEST. --
Sep 16 21:01:40 masi dbus[1248]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service'
Sep 16 21:01:41 masi dbus[1248]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Sep 16 21:01:55 masi google-chrome.desktop[25690]: A Parser-blocking, cross-origin script, http://js.indexww.com/ht/mtvfi.js, is invoked via document.write. This may be blocked by the browser if the device has poor network connectivity.
Sep 16 21:01:55 masi google-chrome.desktop[25690]: A Parser-blocking, cross-origin script, http://js.indexww.com/ht/mtvfi.js, is invoked via document.write. This may be blocked by the browser if the device has poor network connectivity.
Sep 16 21:01:55 masi google-chrome.desktop[25690]: A Parser-blocking, cross-origin script, http://ad.doubleclick.net/adj/test.home/htb;tile=1;sz=980x120;ord=6803931308961870?, is invoked via document.write. This may be blocked by the browser if the device has poor network connectivity.
Sep 16 21:01:56 masi google-chrome.desktop[25690]: A Parser-blocking, cross-origin script, http://netti.mtvmedia.fi/eas?EASformat=jsvars::EAScus=291&c1-5-0=1028, is invoked via document.write. This may be blocked by the browser if the device has poor network connectivity.
Sep 16 21:01:56 masi google-chrome.desktop[25690]: A Parser-blocking, cross-origin script, http://netti.mtvmedia.fi/eas?EASformat=jsvars::EAScus=291&c1-5-0=1028, is invoked via document.write. This may be blocked by the browser if the device has poor network connectivity.
Sep 16 21:02:26 masi google-chrome.desktop[25690]: A Parser-blocking, cross-origin script, http://js.indexww.com/ht/mtvfi.js, is invoked via document.write. This may be blocked by the browser if the device has poor network connectivity.
Sep 16 21:02:26 masi google-chrome.desktop[25690]: A Parser-blocking, cross-origin script, http://js.indexww.com/ht/mtvfi.js, is invoked via document.write. This may be blocked by the browser if the device has poor network connectivity.
Sep 16 21:02:26 masi google-chrome.desktop[25690]: A Parser-blocking, cross-origin script, http://ad.doubleclick.net/adj/test.home/htb;tile=1;sz=980x120;ord=6803931308961870?, is invoked via document.write. This may be blocked by the browser if the device has poor network connectivity.
```

OS: Debian 8.5 64 bit
Linux kernel: 4.6 of backports
Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX303UA
SPSS-statistics: IBM SPSS Statistics Desktop v23 (Linux)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need Oracle's Java, not Debian's default JRE/... Do as root, following the guide [here](https://wiki.debian.org/JavaPackage)

1. `apt-get purge openjdk-7-jre` and/or relevant by leaving the some data of the packages in your system; may be needed later
2. Add the following in `/etc/apt/sources.list`

   ```
   # Debian 8 "Jessie"
   deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib
   ```
3. Update packages and install `java-package` from *contrib*

   ```
   apt-get update && apt-get install java-package
   ```
4. Download Oracle Java in their website; choose .tar.gz for Debian [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html)
5. Build the .tar as non-root because the installer can damage your system and particularly `/etc/`

   ```
   fakeroot make-jpkg jre-8u102-linux-x64.tar.gz
   ```
6. Install the binary created as root

   ```
   su
   dpkg -i oracle-java8-jre_8u102_amd64.deb
   ```
7. Configure default Java version but unable to find package without errors

   ```
   # http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/310790/16920
   # successfully done here; you can ignore JDK errors because JRE only needed
   ```
8. Run SPSS now by the program `spssclient` in `/opt/IBM/SPSS/Statistics/23/bin/` as `masi` which is the default configuration here; which starts succussefully GUI of SPSS

   ```
   masi@masi:/opt/IBM/SPSS/Statistics/23/bin# ./spssclient 

   root@masi:/opt/IBM/SPSS/Statistics/23/bin# ls -la | grep spssclient 
   -rwxrwxr-x  1 masi masi      178 Sep 19 12:17 spssclient
   ```
9. Make alias for the program because it is much work to find it each time there in `/opt`; etc put in your `$HOME/.bashrc`

   ```
   alias spss="/opt/IBM/SPSS/Statistics/23/bin/spssclient"
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
apt-get install dbus
```

consider installing Oracle Java and check the install-time write-rights to the installation target folder for the user account You use :)

Comment: There seems to be some dependency problems in my system, please see the body.